# {"Message":"An error has occurred."} exactly mean/error it is

Tags: jmeter

When I have executed the JMeter load test script. I am getting "Response code: 500" and also response data

`{"Message": "An error has occurred."}`

I have tried with different Id's to pass the data.

Sampler Result:

```
Thread Name: Thread Group 1-1
Sample Start: 2019-05-11 17:45:32 IST
Load time: 36
Connect Time: 0
Latency: 36
Size in bytes: 358
Sent bytes:5783
Headers size in bytes: 322
Body size in bytes: 36
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 1
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""): text
Response code: 500
Response message: Internal Server Error

HTTPSampleResult fields:
ContentType: application/json; charset=utf-8
DataEncoding: utf-8
```

Response data:

`{"Message":"An error has occurred."}`

Expected Result: Should place an order(such as e-commerce)
Actual Result: Unable to place an order.

Answer (score 0):

The client application gets an HTTP status code of 500 with the message "Internal Server Error" as a response for API calls. The 500 Internal Server error could be caused by an error during the execution of any policy within Edge or by an error on the target/backend server.

The HTTP status code 500 is a generic error response. It means that the server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request. This error is usually returned by the server when no other error code is suitable.

https://docs.apigee.com/api-platform/troubleshoot/runtime/500-internal-server-error-0

Normally, you request is malformed and have break some logic/validation or which is not served by the server due to some error.

What can be done?:-

1. Execute the request manually using browser to check if there is a problem in the server in serving your request.
2. Your http request is not correct. Check for correlation/mandatory dynamic parameters. Use any sniffing tool like fiddler to capture two request and compare them to get the dynamic parameters and see if you have correlated them or not.